# Using apicontroller in mvc via ajax to create a wallpostfunction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to display wallposts on a userpage in mvc using an apicontroller and ajax. THe problem I'm having is that the function in my view doesn't pass or receive data and I'm not sure why.

This is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web.Http;
using webDate.Models;

namespace webDate.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/wallpost")]
    public class PostApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Get")]
        public PostModel[] ListPosts(string Id)
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            return db.posts.Where(p => p.PostReceiver.Equals(Id)).ToArray();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Post")]
        public void Post(PostIndexViewModel postIndex)
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var poster = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            var receiver = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(postIndex.PostReceiver));

            var post = new PostModel
            {
                PostContent = postIndex.PostContent,
                Poster = poster.Id,
                PostReceiver = receiver.Id
            };
            db.posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }


    }
}
```

And this is my View:

```
@model webDate.Models.ProfileViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Profile";
}



<div class="row" style="margin-top:5rem">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="@Url.Action("UserAllPhotos", "Home", new { Id = Model.Id })" class="card-img" style="width:9rem ; margin-left: 1rem ; height:9rem" alt="User Photo">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">@Model.Username</h3>
                    <h4 class="card-title">Age: @Model.Age</h4>
                    <p class=" card-text"> @Model.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row" style=" margin-top : 3rem ;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="card-header bg-transparent border-bottom">
                        Wall of posts
                    </h3>
                    <p class="card-text"> All them posts </p>
                    <p class="card-text"> All them posts </p>
                    <p class="card-text"> All them posts </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function update() {
            $('#wall-output').text('');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/wallpost/get",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { Id: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id))},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (posts) {
                        posts.forEach(function (post) {
                            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                            tr.append(
                            '<div class="row">' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">' +
                                    '<div class="thumbnail">' +
                                    //'<img src= class="card-img" style="width:9rem ; margin-left: 1rem ; height:9rem" alt="User Photo">' +
                                            '<div class="caption">' +
                                                '<h3>' + 'From: ' + postModel.Poster + ' </h3>' +
                                                '<p class="message">' + postModel.PostContent + '</p>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>');
                            $('#wall-output').append(tr);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error please try again");
                    }
                });

        }


        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            var PostViewModel = new Object();
            PostViewModel.PostContent = $("#message").val().trim();
            PostViewModel.UserWall = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/wallpost/post',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: PostViewModel,
                success: function (d) {
                    document.getElementById("postform").reset();
                    update();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error please try again");
                }
            });
        });
        update();
    });
    </script>
    }
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Wall</h1>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody id="wall-output"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form name="postform" id="postform" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PostContent">Wall Post:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Create" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my model:

```
    namespace webDate.Models
{
    public class PostModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Poster { get; set; }
        public string PostReceiver { get; set; }
        public string PostContent { get; set; }



    }
}
```

And my other model:

```
    namespace webDate.Models
{
    public class PostViewModel
    {
        public string Poster { get; set; }
        public string PostReceiver { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "Wall Post")]
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the ajax function it just goes straight to error and I'm lost about why it does that.

Comment: you are specifying wrong url for ajax request

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly it's the url: '/api/wallpost/post that I need to change?

I'm not sure what the url should request, could you give me a hand?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the /get/ on your ajax call:

`url: "/api/wallpost/get"`

This should work fine:

`url: "/api/wallpost/"`

Comment: Okay, so I tried changing that and I'm still getting an error. From what I understand it has to do with function(post) not being successful. But I'm not sure what in that call that goes wrong.

Comment: So I changed according to what you answered which was really helpful but it still generates an error when calling the method.